# What does shellcheck warning SC2129 “Consider using { cmd1; cmd2; } >> file instead of individual redirects.” mean?

Tags: bash, debugging, output

I have this `shellcheck` warning I can't figure out:

```
In /mnt/e/bin/iconic line 540:
            printf "FALSE|" >> "$IconsRaw"           # Select field number 1
            ^-- SC2129: Consider using { cmd1; cmd2; } >> file instead of individual redirects.
```

I've noticed many of us here use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to fix our bash scripts / shell commands so I hope the question is on topic.

---

As per comments posting relevant section of bash script:

```
    if [[ "$X" == "?" || "$Y" == "?" ]] ; then
        : # Bad X or Y offset usually "Link to Name.ext~" (backup name)
    else
        let i++
        printf "FALSE|" >> "$IconsRaw"           # Select field number 1
        printf "%s|" "$i" >> "$IconsRaw"         # 2
        printf "%s|" "${File##*/}" >> "$IconsRaw"
        printf "%s|" "$Linkless" >> "$IconsRaw"  # 4
        printf "%s|" "$Date" >> "$IconsRaw"      # 5
        printf "%s|" "$X" >> "$IconsRaw"         # 6
        echo   "$Y" >> "$IconsRaw"               # 7
    fi
```

---

### Solution

Thanks to accepted answer and comments I've learned that `shellcheck` not only catches errors in your code, but also suggests performance improvements. In this case the filename `$IconsRaw` was being opened and closed many times with each `printf` and `echo`.

The more efficient bash code:

```
    # X,Y screen coordinates invalid on backup files ending with "~"
    ! [[ "$X" == "?" || "$Y" == "?" ]] && { let i++; echo \
        "FALSE|$i|${File##*/}|$Linkless|$Date|$X|$Y" >> "$IconsRaw"; }
```

Comment: I think it's just suggesting doing a single write instead of multiple open/seek/write operations - but it might be clearer if you posted a larger sample of the script

Comment: When the message is too terse, you can look at [the wiki page for SC2129](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2129) which has a full length description with examples

Comment: @thatotherguy Your comment could be an answer if it included relevant parts of the link in the body. It would help others and I for one would gladly upvote it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume your script has multiple instances of `>> "$IconsRaw"`. That message is suggesting redirecting the output only once and grouping the commands in a subshell. Presumably to avoid the overhead of opening and closing the file multiple times.

So, instead of this:

```
    printf "FALSE|" >> "$IconsRaw"           # Select field number 1
    printf "%s|" "$i" >> "$IconsRaw"         # 2
    printf "%s|" "${File##*/}" >> "$IconsRaw"
    printf "%s|" "$Linkless" >> "$IconsRaw"  # 4
    printf "%s|" "$Date" >> "$IconsRaw"      # 5
    printf "%s|" "$X" >> "$IconsRaw"         # 6
    echo   "$Y" >> "$IconsRaw"               # 7
```

This:

```
{
    printf "FALSE|"            # Select field number 1
    printf "%s|" "$i"          # 2
    printf "%s|" "${File##*/}" 
    printf "%s|" "$Linkless"   # 4
    printf "%s|" "$Date"       # 5
    printf "%s|" "$X"          # 6
    printf "%s\n" "$Y"         # 7
} >> "$IconsRaw"
```

Bu that's also a needless repetition of `printf` and it is more efficient to just do:

```
printf '%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n' \
      'FALSE' "$i" "${File##*/}" "$Linkless" \
      "$Date" "$X" "$Y" >> "$IconsRaw"
```

Comment: printf also can write all arguments using only one format specifier provided. So you could have one printf and multiple args to it as alternative. Or use a function. Functions support redirection in declaration

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix please see updated answer. There's no need for multiple calls to `printf` at all and if you only want `\n` on the last field, then just only use `\n` for the last field.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy excellent point of concatenating all fields into single `printf` call. By the same token a single `echo` could be used with shorter code (no `%s`) but I wonder if that is less efficient? Terdon thanks for your answer. Accepting now.